# Show Multiple Select Attribute in a CMS Block

Tags: magento2, attributes, phtml

I want to show Multiple Select Attributes in a CMS Block.
In the Block I used this code:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="ausgezeichnet" template="Magento_Theme/templates/html/auszeichnungen.phtml"}}
```

auszeichnungen.phtml looks like this

```
<?php       
   $_prodID = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
   $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_prodID );
?>

<?php echo $_product->getData('auszeichnungen') ?>
<?php
echo "Hello World";
?>
```

But nothing appears on the Product Page - neither "Hello World". The Block itself is showing, but just the headline, not the attributes values ...

Comment: you are check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/158600/85907 ???

Comment: I did, its about multiple cms blocks. I just need one - and the one is not working.